# AJAX Toolkit for ASp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Is there any ajax toolkit for asp.net MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MVC does not have ViewState or the Web Forms postback model the AjaxControlToolkit will not work with it.

There is a project to do this (http://mvccontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/) but it's not yet released.

There are numerous blogs where have got different controls working but to be honest I'd suggest looking at jQuery and its plugins (http://www.jqueryui.com/). MVC lends itself far more naturally to these, it is not control-based.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another resource talking about this: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCPreview4UsingAjaxAndAjaxForm.aspx

In addition, ASP.NET MVC lends itself quite easily to making your own amazing ajax controls, especially when combined with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

The emphasis in ASP.NET MVC is more on HTML and client-side code when talking about user-control similar to those in the AJAX Toolkit - you may like to check out the excellent http://www.jqueryui.com/ for some good client-side controls.